# How to sort an NSArray of known objects such that the FIRST record is ensured to be equal to a known object?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sorting, ios4, nsarray

If I have an object and setup such as:

```
MyObject *objectOne = ....;

NSArray *arrayOfMyObjects = [self.someObject valueForKey=@"myObjects"] allObjects];
```

where *valueForKey=@"objects"* is an NSMutableSet of MyObject types,

How exactly do I use sorting to ENSURE (or at least attempt to ensure) that *objectOne* is equal to
`[arrayOfMyObjects objectAtIndex:0]` ?

Basically ensuring that the first object of the NSArray is equal to a known object I have?
This is for the purposes of a UITableView and making sure the top most record is *objectOne* when it is loaded?

I'm guessing there's some sort descriptors trickery required but not quite sure the syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a comparator block to ensure that it is first:

```
MyObject *objectOne;
NSArray *array = [[self.someObject valueForKey:@"myObjects"] allObjects];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if(obj1 == objectOne) return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    if(obj2 == objectOne) return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

The typecast on the returns is to remove the compiler warning for incorrect argument types. `NSOrdered...` are of type `enum _NSComparisonResult`, and the method expects a NSComparator, which is defined as `NSComparisonResult ^(id obj1, id obj2)`, but `NSComparisonResult` and `enum _NSComparisonResult` are not the same.

Comment: Tried using this. Doesn't seem to do the job? What exactly is going on with a return of NSOrderedAscending or NSOrderedDescending? Is that saying to move the object up one or down one?

Comment: Changing the first two returns to NSOrderedDescending accomplishes the job!

Comment: @Straddle I thought NSOrderedAscending meant obj1 should come before obj2, but maybe I'm backwards. Have you tried having the second ascending? They should not be the same.

Comment: not sure but with both set to NSOrderedDescending it works like a charm everytime! If one is Descending and one is Ascending, it won't really change will it? because objectOne will just get shifted up or down constantly depending if it's set to obj1 or obj2 coming in? Know what I mean?

Comment: @Straddle If you have one wrong and one right, it will only work as long as objectOne gets passed in the one with the right return. If it gets passed in the other one, it will tell the array that the other object should go before objectOne. Use test arrays of {objectOne, someObject} and {someObject, objectOne} and see if it returns the right order for both.